# How to use (magic) trackpad scrolling to scroll only one page up/down with Preview?

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

When I view pdf file with Preview, I can use wheel click mouse to scroll one page up/down.
How can I do the same thing with trackpad? Using two finger scroll gives me two much scroll. I need to scroll up/down only one pdf page with trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have a Magic Trackpad, but on my Magic Mouse its the same gesture that is used for **forward** and **back** in Safari. In the mouse its swipe two fingers to the left and right, so if the Trackpad is just like that of a macbook, Im 99% sure its swipe **three** fingers to the right or left.

Hope it Helps!
Kevin